# Visual Studio - UWP Designer doesn't "render"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, designer

[image: Screenshot]=

The WPF Designer works as expected, this is only happening with UWP Projects. I have tried setting the target platform to 10240, with no difference. I'm running the latest Insider Preview build 14279.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see the code, but from what I can assume, you're probably missing some styles for the `<button />` you're trying to render, that's why it looks like it's "invisible" (In the screenshots it seems like the designer is running ok, no exceptions are thrown or anything of the likes.

Comment: Compiling and running the application gives this result: http://i.imgur.com/uBYjQsr.png
So it's definitely something with the XAML Designer.